# what is the distribution of prime numbers and their powers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I know that Prime number theorem says that the that $P_n$ ~ $\log(n)n$ or $\frac{P_n}{\log(n)n}=1$ as n goes to infinty

My question is what is a ~ formula for not just prime numbers but all numbers that factorization looks like $P_m^n$

$n$ and $m$ are natural numbers.

what is the distribution of primes and their powers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function

Comment: No it is the Riemann prime power counting  function. Use Google.